# How to format the mybatis generator SSL URL

Tags: mysql, ssl, mybatis

How do you correctly format a mysql SSL URL to use in the generatorConfiguration XML file please?

The SSL URL I am trying to use working fine if I test it directly in Java code but refuses to connect when I use it in in the generatorConfiguration.xml file.

Non working generatorConfiguration.xml:

```
<jdbcConnection driverClass="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
  connectionURL="jdbc:mysql://the_host/my_database?autoReconnect=true&amp;requireSSL=true&amp;useSSL=true&amp;verifyServerCertificate=false&amp;trustCertificateKeyStoreUrl=file://opt/java/jdk1.8.0_241/jre/lib/security/cacerts&amp;trustCertificateKeyStorePassword=changeit" 
userId="the_username" 
password="the_password" />
```

Execution failed for task ':mbGenerator'.

> Could not create connection to database server. Attempted reconnect 3 times. Giving up.

Working Java Code:

```
String url = "jdbc:mysql://the_host/my_database"
+ "?requireSSL=true&useSSL=true&verifyServerCertificate=false&"
+ "trustCertificateKeyStoreUrl=file:/opt/java/jdk1.8.0_241/jre/lib/security/cacerts"
+ "&trustCertificateKeyStorePassword=changeit";
String user = "the_username";
String password = "the_password";
Class<?> dbDriver = Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");         
con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);         
ps = con.prepareStatement("select * from user");
```

Attempting to generate the model and mapper classes from the mysql database fails.

Comment: I'm not sure, but there should be three slashes between `file:` and `opt`, maybe? i.e. the protocol `file://` and the absolute path `/opt/...`.

Comment: I was hopeful but 3 slashes didn't do the trick. I have tried /, // and /// but no luck. I am sure its something simple like this though :-P Thanks